# CursorAdapter row/list item height

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I've currently worked out a way to use 5 different row layouts in my listview/cursoradapter.
However I've come across the issue that i need to be able to change the row height.

I have click to dismiss and swipe to dismiss functionality in my listview.They work by replacing the current cursor with a cursorwrapper and thus hiding a row.

By doing this, the listview takes the height from the removed view and applies it to next row in the listview. By doing this, the row takes the wrong height.

What I think I my question is, is how do I force the bindView/newView method to give the row the proper height.

My code:

**newView:**

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v;

    switch (cursor.getInt(Card.CARD_TYPE_COLUMN_INDEX)) {
    case CardViewModel.DepartmentInformation: {
        v =  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.department_information_card, parent, false);

        DepartmentInformationViewHolder holder = new DepartmentInformationViewHolder();
        holder.mHeader = (CardHeader) v.findViewById(R.id.department_title);
        holder.mHeading = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.department_heading_with_remove_option);
        holder.mRemoveButton = (CardRemoveButton) v.findViewById(R.id.department_heading_remove_button);
        holder.mRemovableHeader = (CardHeader) v.findViewById(R.id.department_heading_title);
        holder.mDescription = (CardText) v.findViewById(R.id.department_description);
        holder.mGallery = (CardGallery) v.findViewById(R.id.department_gallery);
        holder.mButton = (CardButton) v.findViewById(R.id.department_button);

        v.setTag(holder);

        break;
    }
```

**bindView**

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    String content = cursor.getString(Card.CARD_CONTENT_COLUMN_INDEX);
    int itemType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());

    switch (itemType) {

    case CardViewModel.DepartmentInformation: {

        DepartmentInformationViewModel viewModel = mGson.fromJson(content, DepartmentInformationViewModel.class);
        DepartmentInformationViewHolder holder = (DepartmentInformationViewHolder) view.getTag();

        /**
         * Do the binding of all the components.
         */
        if (cursor.getInt(Card.CARD_REMOVABLE_COLUMN_INDEX) == 1) {
            holder.mHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bindCardTitle(context, holder.mHeader, viewModel.getTitle());
            holder.mHeading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.mHeading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bindCardTitle(context, holder.mRemovableHeader, viewModel.getTitle());
            bindRemoveCardButton(context, holder.mRemoveButton, cursor, cursor.getPosition(), cursor.getString(0));
            holder.mHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        bindCardText(context, holder.mDescription, viewModel.getDescription());
        bindCardGallery(context, holder.mGallery, viewModel.getGallery());
        bindCardButton(context, holder.mButton, viewModel.getButton());

        break;
    }

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    switch (cursor.getInt(Card.CARD_TYPE_COLUMN_INDEX)) {
    case CardViewModel.DepartmentInformation: {
        return CardViewModel.DepartmentInformation;
    }
    case CardViewModel.EstablishmentInformation: {
        return CardViewModel.EstablishmentInformation;
    }
    case CardViewModel.EstablishmentOutdoorNavigation: {
        return CardViewModel.EstablishmentOutdoorNavigation;
    }
    case CardViewModel.SuggestionInDoorNavigation: {
        return CardViewModel.SuggestionInDoorNavigation;
    }
    default: {
        return 4;
    }
    }
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 5;
}
```

Do you guys know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. It was not problem in the cursoradapter, nor the logic of the ListView.
The problem was in the library I was using for the animation of the swipe to dismiss.

I found the following webpage: https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/issues/7.

It describes how the height of views is reset. Replacing the following worked for me:

@line 379 in my version of SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.java

```
// TODO: If problems are found with the height of cards. This might be the problem.
// ORIGINAL: lp.height = originalHeight;
lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

@line 302 in my version of SwipeDismissTouchListener.java

```
// TODO: If problems are found with the height of cards. This might be the problem.
// ORIGINAL: lp.height = originalHeight;
lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Height of item should be `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` 
Each item will take the space it needs and you have different heights for each item in the listview.

The below example gives varying heights based on how much text is supplied.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#CC8439"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#3399FF"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resrawid"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No this has nothing the value that is set to the height of the row. It is the view recycling that's my problem. I have a layout for a view, that is being used for another view. The problem lies in the fact that in one, I show a viewpager and in the other I set it to Visibility.GONE. It does not reset the height, when it recycles the layout.